# XMLResolver Compile Errors

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

So, I'm trying to use XMLResolver to load an xml file.  It works fine when I create an xmlreader from a filename but fails when I do so using a stringreader.  It gives me an `XslLoadException: XSLT compiler error.` The inner exception is `"An entry with the same key already exists."`

```
    public override object GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, string role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
    {
        string f = Path.Combine(@"C:\tmp", Path.GetFileName(absoluteUri.ToString()));
        string testaxCont = @"<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"" version=""1.0""><xsl:template name=""J""/></xsl:stylesheet>";
        string testaxCont2 = File.ReadAllText(f);
        bool j = testaxCont.Equals(testaxCont2); //This equals true
        XmlReader tmp = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(f))); //crash
//            XmlReader tmp = XmlReader.Create(f); //don't crash
        return tmp;
    }
```

---

```
testax.xslt    
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"><xsl:include href="testax2.xsl" /></xsl:stylesheet>

testax2.xsl
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"><xsl:template name="J"/></xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to change the broken line to `XmlReader tmp = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(f)),null,f);` With a file it has a base URI but with a string it is missing.